# Separate a csv for processing

Tags: python, csv

I am new to Python and love it. However, I have a problem and hope someone can help.

I have a string of values separated by commas and want to use a loop to individually process each of the values in turn.

e.g.

string = '1,2,3,4,5,6,'

I want to take the first value '1' and process it before moving on to the next value.

Comment: `for x in string.split(',') :
  foo(x)
`

if you have a trailing comma the last entry will be blank :)

Answer (score 3):

In the case above, you can use the `split` method to split a string by commas and then iterate through the resulting list:

```
In [1]: s = '1,2,3,4,5,6,'

In [2]: s.split(',')
Out[2]: ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '']

In [3]: for i in s.split(','):
   ...:     if i:
   ...:         print i
   ...:         
   ...:         
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

`split` returns a list, so what we do here is iterate through the resulting list and then check to see if the field is empty or not; it not process. We do this check because your string ends in a `,`, which as you can see returns an empty string. Also note that this splits on **all** commas - not just those that separate values.

For the case above, that should be fine, but in the case where you want to do more advanced handling of CSV information, the `csv` module provides numerous options for doing so. For example:

```
In [1]: import csv

In [2]: s = '1,2,3,"four, five",6'

In [3]: for item in csv.reader([s]):
   ...:     print item
   ...:     
   ...:     
['1', '2', '3', 'four, five', '6']
```

Here we use the `csv` module to read the string, and the `item` returned represents the comma-separated string, but with the special `"four, five"` value still treated as one value. However note that in the case of a single string, this returns a single list comprised of the comma-separated string elements. As @JonClements points out, a clean way to iterate through the elements themselves is to call `next` on `csv.reader([s])`, which will return the list itself:

```
In [1]: import csv

In [2]: s = '1,2,3,"four, five",6'

In [3]: for item in next(csv.reader([s])):
   ...:     print item
   ...:     
   ...:     
1
2
3
four, five
6
```

Comment: Just to note that `for col in next(csv.reader([s])): print col` makes more sense for single line inputs

Comment: @JonClements Great point as always - I'll update to note that.